# Compiling using gfortran on older code

Tags: compilation, fortran, gfortran

I need to run an old program found here: http://netlib.sandia.gov/conformal/ under the title "kirch1" in the list. I have absolutely no experience running fortran code, but I would like to do so from my Mac OS X 10.10 command line.

I know I have the 'gfortan' compiler installed on my system, but I'm not sure if this doesn't like this older code. When I run `gfortran KIRCH1.f` (this file is the one above) I get the following error:

```
KIRCH1.f:266.8:

      x(2) = -1. + dx                                                   
        1
Warning: Array reference at (1) is out of bounds (2 > 1) in dimension 1
KIRCH1.f:200.21:

      common /param1/ nq2,c2,x2(20),z2(20),qwork2(460),betam2(20)       
                     1
Warning: Padding of 4 bytes required before 'c2' in COMMON 'param1' at (1); reorder elements or use -fno-align-commons
KIRCH1.f:285.21:

      common /param1/ nq,c,x(20),z(20),qwork(460),betam(20)             
                     1
Warning: Padding of 4 bytes required before 'c' in COMMON 'param1' at (1); reorder elements or use -fno-align-commons
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gaussj_", referenced from:
      _qinitx_ in ccoKtvwZ.o
  "_ns01a_", referenced from:
      _ksolv_ in ccoKtvwZ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This error seems to be do to the syntax in the code? I doubt there is anything wrong with the code itself, so I'm thinking its something to do with my systems interpretation of the code (for lack of a better way of phrasing this)

I have no fortran programming experience, I should mention. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

As suggested by Ed Smith
I run `gfortran sclibdbl.f KIRCH1.f` but I still get the following warnings:

```
KIRCH1.f:266.8:

      x(2) = -1. + dx                                                   
        1
Warning: Array reference at (1) is out of bounds (2 > 1) in dimension 1
KIRCH1.f:200.21:

      common /param1/ nq2,c2,x2(20),z2(20),qwork2(460),betam2(20)       
                     1
Warning: Padding of 4 bytes required before 'c2' in COMMON 'param1' at (1); reorder elements or use -fno-align-commons
KIRCH1.f:285.21:

      common /param1/ nq,c,x(20),z(20),qwork(460),betam(20)             
                     1
Warning: Padding of 4 bytes required before 'c' in COMMON 'param1' at (1); reorder elements or use -fno-align-commons
```

Comment: Those first things aren't errors, but warnings (based on the old ways of writing code).  Your error is from the linker.  To solve that you'll need to find some instructions: at least telling you where to find those other functions/subroutines referenced.

Comment: Ah I see thanks. Those subroutines can be found at http://www.netlib.org/conformal/sclibdbl. What would I need to do to link them together?

Comment: The linked code is using the old-school convention of declaring assumed size (dummy argument) arrays a dimension of `1`, eg: `double precision  x(1)`. You can safely ignore that warning, turn off bounds checking, or change such declarations to `double precision  x(*)`.

Comment: The other warning is because (probably) `nq` is a 4 byte integer and everything else is  `double precision` (again probably, since you havent shared the code ).  You can ignore that, or if the warning really irks you do as it says and move the integer to the end of the list (taking care of course to change every occurrence of the common statement the same way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following compiled for me:

```
gfortran sclibdbl.f KIRCH1.f
```

where `KIRCH1.f` is the code from http://netlib.sandia.gov/conformal/kirch1 and `sclibdb1.f` is the code from http://netlib.org/conformal/sclibdbl.

You were just missing the required subroutines `gaussj` and `ns01a` which are referenced in the KIRCH1 source code but included in sclibdbl. The code from netlib.org/conformal/sclibdbl includes both the `gaussj` and `ns01a` subroutine (note the underscore is added to routine names by default in gfortran).

As @francescalus noted, it's modern fortran compiler and old school FORTRAN code. The warning is because modern fortran is far more explicit about array extents. In this code, x is passed with size 1 to `yxtran()` which is okay as passing is a reference to the start of array. When element 2 is accessed the modern fortran compiler gets worried. You can remove the two common block errors by adding the `-fno-align-commons` flag to the compiler. The x(1) error could be removed by replacing x(1) on line 258 with x(n-1). Personally, I wouldn't worry unless you notice problems/unexpected behavior when you run the code (especially as it's from netlib).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you read my edit above I still get some warnings. Did that happen for you as well?

Comment: Added a bit more explanation of the warnings, hope this helps (basically don't worry about it unless it goes wrong).

Comment: `-fno-align-commons` seems like it might negatively impact performance, aligning things sub-optimally in memory.   Other fixes ( including simply ignoring the warning ) are probably preferable.

Comment: @EdSmith This is probably not the best way to ask, but I feel posting another question might be a bit overkill- How do I open and plot the data that is written to the file "fort.10"?

Comment: Looks like it's just formatted output from the source code (i.e. you can open it as a text file). You can just copy it into excel or use something like gnuplot if the format is simple. You could also write a script in matlab or python/matplotlib which reads this (using similar format statements as used in the fortran output). Both matlab and matplotlib have streamline functions. There may already be a high level plotting language example for this script online.